# Using SFINAE to detect a member function

Tags: c++, sfinae, c++98

In C++11, to find out whether a class has a member function `size`, you could define the following test helper:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_size_fn
{
    typedef char (& yes)[1];
    typedef char (& no)[2];

    template <typename C> static yes check(decltype(&C::size));
    template <typename> static no check(...);

    static bool const value = sizeof(check<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Is there a similar trick for doing this in C++98 without relying on compiler extensions such as `typeof`?

Comment: That'll detect data members, too.

Comment: This might be useful: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector -- _Edit:_ also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence (don't stop at the first answer)

Comment: @jrok That's ok, it'll be used in a template function that will then cause a compilation error if it's not a function - I can live with that.

Comment: @nijansen It'll also trigger a hard error if `size` is private instead of SFINAE. You'll have to live with that too in C++98, unless you switch to the technique from gx_'s comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, your detection is potentially erroneous.

The problem is that all you are detecting is that `C` has a member `size`:

- it could be an attribute
- it could be a method with whatever signature
- there could even be several methods (with various signatures)

If you wish to harden the detection, you should attempt to detect only the *right* `size` (for whatever right is). [Here is such a hardened detection](http://ideone.com/JKo8p5).

```
template <typename T>
class has_size {
private:
  typedef char Yes;
  typedef Yes No[2];

  template <typename U, U> struct really_has;

  template <typename C> static Yes& Test(really_has <size_t (C::*)() const,
                                        &C::size>*);

  // EDIT: and you can detect one of several overloads... by overloading :)
  template <typename C> static Yes& Test(really_has <size_t (C::*)(),
                                        &C::size>*);

  template <typename> static No& Test(...);

public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(Test<T>(0)) == sizeof(Yes);
};
```

**Edit:** [with overloads](http://ideone.com/RGeZTX).

The trick to deal with incorrect `size` members is the `really_has` structure. I make no pretense that it is perfect, though...

In C++11, [things are simpler](http://ideone.com/AmaBrN) (though no less verbose) because you can detect things by *use* directly. The equivalent trait is thus:

```
template <typename T>
class has_size {
private:
  typedef char Yes;
  typedef Yes No[2];

  template<typename C> static auto Test(void*)
    -> decltype(size_t{std::declval<C const>().size()}, Yes{});

  template<typename> static No& Test(...);

public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(Test<T>(0)) == sizeof(Yes);
};
```

However, the recommended method in C++ is *not to use traits* if you can; in functions for example you can use `decltype` right in the type signature.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm bound to C++98 here; can I allow both `size_t size()` and `size_t size() const` as signature somehow?

Comment: @nijansen: you can, but does it make sense ? Note that if your function is `void doSomething(C const& container)` then it is required to use a `const` method :) . See the edited answer for how to.

Comment: Yeah, I've had to change that into passing it by value, because I have to use some libraries that don't really like const correctness ... I still want my `has_size` metafunction to be compatible with these library containers and the STL containers

Comment: @nijansen: ouch, passing by value is though, really. You realize it implies a copy of the container ? You might be better off providing a proxy `template <typename T> class Proxy { Proxy(T& t): _t(t) {} size_t size() const { return _t.size(); } ... };` and then `Proxy proxy(container); doSomething(proxy);`

Comment: You're right - that's a brilliant idea. Thanks